# How to use polymorphism in functional programming?

Tags: oop, clojure, functional-programming, polymorphism

How to use polymorphism in functional programming (with dynamic type system)?

Let's consider following example (first in OOP second in FP). The program is very simple - there are list of figures and we need to draw all of them, different figures use different drawing algorithms.

In OOP it can be done trivially, but how to do it in FP? Especially in languages with dynamic type system, like Scheme, Clojure (without static type resolving at compile time)?

I created simple code ( live version http://tinkerbin.com/0C3y8D9Z , press 'Run' button ). I used if/else switch in FP sample, but it's a very bad approach. How such problem can be solved better?

Samples are in JavaScript, but it's only for purpose of simplicity, it would be interesting to see a solution in any functional language with dynamic typing system.

**OOP**

```
var print = function(message){document.write(message + "\n<br/>")}

// Object Oriented Approach.
var circle = {
  draw: function(){print("drawing circle ...")}
}
var rectangle = {
  draw: function(){print("drawing rectangle ...")}
}

var objects = [circle, rectangle]
objects.forEach(function(o){
  o.draw()
})
```

**FP**

```
var print = function(message){document.write(message + "\n<br/>")}

// Functional Approach.
var circle = {type: 'Circle'}
var drawCircle = function(){print("drawing circle ...")}

var rectangle = {type: 'Rectangle'}
var drawRectangle = function(){print("drawing rectangle ...")}

var objects = [circle, rectangle]
objects.forEach(function(o){
  if(o.type == 'Circle') drawCircle(o)
  else if(o.type == 'Rectangle') drawRectangle(o)
  else throw new Error('unknown type!')
})
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OO polymorphism is not a part of functional programming. However some functional languages (e.g. clojure) have oo polymorphism.

Another kind of polymorphism is multimethods

```
(def circle {:type :circle
             :radius 50})

(def rectangle {:type :rectangle
                :width 5
                :height 10})

(defmulti draw :type)

(defmethod draw :circle [object]
  (println "circle: radius = " (:radius object)))

(defmethod draw :rectangle [object]
  (println "rectangle: "
           "width = " (:width object)
           "height = " (:height object)))

(doseq [o [rectangle circle]] (draw o))
=> rectangle:  width =  5 height =  10
   circle: radius =  50
```

Or you just can use functional style

```
(defn circle [] (println "drawing circle ..."))
(defn rectangle [] (println "drawing rectangle ..."))

(def objects [circle rectangle])

(doseq [o objects] (o))
=> drawing circle ...
   drawing rectangle ...
```

Comment: I like your point about multimethods, but I don't understand what you're getting at with the second code snippet prefaced by _Or you just can use functional style_...

Comment: @DaoWen In FP solution is getting achieved very easily without additional abstractions.

Comment: In that case I think you have an error in your code because it doesn't make sense. `(def objects [draw-circle draw-rectangle])`??? Where are those functions defined?

Comment: """OO polymorphism is not a part of functional programming""" maybe, but the problem with shapes - it's a general problem, it should be solved somehow.

As with functional style - `draw-circle draw-rectangle` vs. just a `draw` - it consumes the most precious resource - additional memory in our brain.

Comment: @AlexeyPetrushin Subtype polymorphism (which is what OOP guys call just "polymorphism") isn't the only kind of polymorphism. mobyte goes on to describe some of such alternatives. Are you ignoring that part?

Comment: @DaoWen There is no error. We have collection of two functions.

Comment: """... Are you ignoring that part?""" No, I agreed multimetods (with subtype) solve the problem, I just didn't finished my second comment :).

Comment: I know that functions are first-class and you can create a vector of functions in Clojure—the issue is that you _didn't define_ the functions anywhere. Where did `draw-circle` come from? You only have `circle` and `draw` in either snippet, no `draw-circle` anywhere.

Comment: @AlexeyPetrushin - If you want to use multimethods in JavaScript then this might be helpful: [Multimethod.js](http://krisjordan.com/multimethod-js). Or, better yet, just use [ClojureScript](https://github.com/clojure/clojurescript)!

Comment: @AlexeyPetrushin Okay, good. Now, as for consuming memory: I beg to differ. A collection of functions is as simple as an object with a bunch of methods. The only problem with the code as given here is that it does not tag each function in the data structure with a name (for readers). That, however, is not a fundamental limitation (cf. records in Haskell, including the various extension proposals because the core language's records are rather limited).

Comment: @DaoWen Sorry. I've fixed that. Thanks!

Comment: @delnan """A collection of functions is as simple as an object with a bunch of methods.""" - not exactly, with polymorphism/multimethods I can call `draw` method for any third-party shape, I don't need to even know what type it is to be able to use it. With explicit function names I has to look-up and remember explicit names like `draw-rectangle` or `draw-ellipse`.

Comment: @AlexeyPetrushin In fp solution you don't need to know a "type" neither. You have a bunch of "objects" and they do the job. In this case "explicit function names" is the same as the "explicit type names".

Comment: @mobyte - I think your argument would make a lot more sense if you actually backed it up with some code in your answer. The current code you have—although no longer completely erroneous—still makes no sense. If I have an existing collection containing both squares and circles, how do I generically `draw` all of them in FP-style? My answer would use either multimethods or an explicit [`case`](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/case)—but I don't know how you'd do it with "just a bunch of objects that don't know their types."

Comment: @mobyte - Actually, I think I see the problem here. Alexey's code only has a single member for both his `square` and `circle`: `draw`. I think he's assuming there would be more state involved (e.g. x & y coordinates), but didn't include them for simplicity's sake in the example. If they really only had that single `draw` method then you're totally right, first-class functions are 100% equivalent. If there's additional state involved though, then multimethods are a much better fit.

Answer (score 15):

Your "FP" version is not what I consider the idiomatic FP example. In FP, you often use variants and pattern matching where in OOP you'd use classes and method dispatch. In particular, you only have one `draw` function that already does the dispatch internally:

```
var circle = {type: 'Circle'}
var rectangle = {type: 'Rectangle'}

var draw = function(shape) {
  switch (shape.type) {
    case 'Circle': print("drawing circle ..."); break
    case 'Rectangle': print("drawing rectangle ..."); break
  }
}

var objects = [circle, rectangle]
objects.forEach(draw)
```

(Of course, that is JavaScript. In a functional language you typically have much more elegant and concise syntax for this, e.g.:

```
draw `Circle    = print "drawing circle..."
draw `Rectangle = print "drawing rectangle..."

objects = [`Circle, `Rectangle]
foreach draw objects
```

)

Now, the average OO aficionado will see the above code and say: "But the OO solution is extensible, the above is not!" That's true in the sense that you can easily add new shapes to the OO version and don't have to touch any of the existing ones (or their `draw` functions) when you do. With the FP way, you'd have to go in and extend the `draw` function, and all other operations that may exist.

But what those people fail to see is that the converse is also true: the FP solution is extensible in a way the OO one isn't! Namely, when you add a new *operation* over your existing shapes then you don't need to touch any of the shape definitions, nor existing operations. You simply add another function, whereas with OO, you have to go and modify every class or constructor to include an implementation for the new operation.

That is, there is a dualism here in terms of modularity. The ideal, achieving simultaneous extensibility along both axes is known in literature as "the expression problem", and while various solutions exist (especially in functional languages), they are typically more complex. Hence, in practice you'll often want to decide for one dimension, depending on which dimension is more likely to matter for the problem at hand.

There are other advantages to the functional version. E.g it trivially scales to multi-dispatch or more complex case distinctions. It also is preferable when implementing an algorithm that is complicated and where the different cases are interrelated, so that you want to have the code in one place. As a rule of thumb, whenever you start using the visitor pattern in OO, a functional-style solution would have been more appropriate (and far, far easier).

Some further remarks:

- This different preference in program organisation isn't the central idea of FP. What matters more is discouraging mutable state, and encouraging highly reusable higher-order abstractions.
- The OO community has this habit of inventing new (buzz)words for every old idea. Its use of the term "polymorphism" (which is completely different from what it means elsewhere) is one such example. It says little more than being able to call functions without statically knowing what the callee is. You can do that in any language where functions are first-class values. In that sense, your OO solution is perfectly functional as well.
- Your question has very little to do with types. Both the idiomatic OO and the idiomatic FP solution work in an untyped or typed language.

Answer (score 4):

In Clojure there are Protocols which provide basically the same ad-hoc polymorphism as Haskell's type classes:

```
(defprotocol shape (draw [e]))
(defrecord circle [radius])
(defrecord rectangle [w h])
(extend-protocol shape 
    circle (draw [_] "I am a nice circle")
    rectangle (draw [_] "Can I haz cornerz please?"))
```

You can also extend an existing type:

```
(extend-protocol shape 
   String (draw [_] "I am not a shape, but who cares?"))
```

And then you can apply the draw method to some instances

```
user=> (map draw [(->circle 1) (->rectangle 4 2) "foo"])
("I am a nice circle" "Can I haz cornerz please?" "I am not a shape, but who cares?")
```

Comment: Except clojure doesn't need existential quantification to put these in a list.

Answer (score 2):

There really isn't anything non-functional about your first code sample. Even in languages that have no support for object orientation, you can do the same thing. That is you can create a record/structure/map that contains functions and then put those into your list.

In your simple example where there's only one function, you could also just create a list of functions directly, like `objects = [drawCircle, drawRectangle]`.

Comment: Thanks, hmmm, Yes, but then I don't see the point in using functional programming, it looks like a reinvention of OOP ...

Comment: @AlexeyPetrushin Functional Programming came first, so if anything OOP is a reinvention of FP. Also the FP approach will be more noticably different in cases where the OOP approach relies on mutable state.

Answer (score 2):

In several languages designed primarily for functional programming, there are ways to achieve (ad-hoc, as it is called) polymorphism, though they differ from what you call polymorphism. Haskell, for example, has type classes (not to be confused with classes from classical OOP):

```
class Draw a where
    draw :: a -> SomethingSomthing -- probably IO () for your example, btw
```

(Scala has objects, and also [implicits](http://lambda-the-ultimate.org/node/4039) which apparently parallel or even surpass type classes.)
You can then implement any number of independent types, and make each an instance of the type class (again independently, e.g. in an entirely different module):

```
data Circle = Circle Point Double -- center, radius
data Rectangle = Rect Point Double Double -- center, height, width

instance Draw Circle where
    draw (Circle center radius) = …
instance Draw Rectangle where
    draw (Rect center height width) = …
```

This is probably what you'd use in Haskell, if you actually needed that degree of extensibility. If you have a finite number of cases belonging together (i.e. you could use `sealed` classes in the OOP alternative), you'd likely use algebraic data types (see below).

Another way is to do just what your JS snippet does (which is, by the way, not what you'd do to achieve polymorphism if you had any number of objects of each type, and this version has the same problem): Embed a function that does the polymorphic behavior in each object. In a sense, your "OOP" snippet is already functional.

```
data Drawable = Drawable (Drawable -> SomethingSomething) {- other fields -}
draw (Drawable draw) = draw Drawable
```

Though in a static language, this does not permit different objects to have different attributes.

A more bearable alternative to the bunch of conditions you present, but nevertheless similar and with the same limitation (it's hard to add another shape), is pattern matching with algebraic data types. Other answers on Stackoverflow have explained these well, I'll just give this concrete example in that style:

```
data Shape = Circle {- see second snippet -}
           | Rect {- ditto -}

draw (Circle center radius) = …
draw (Rect center height width) = …
```

Comment: Thanks, but all these samples - Haskel, Skala and type pattern matching are statically typed and resolve functions at the compile time.

Comment: As for embedding function in each object - in real-life scenarios (at least in my experience with ruby and javascript) there are lots of such polymorphic methods (especially if You use meta-programming/code-generation), You can't embed them all.

Comment: @AlexeyPetrushin Type class "methods" (in my example, `draw :: Draw a => a -> SomethingSomething`) are bound late, and thus dispatched at runtime instead of compile time. You can have a list of shapes with different types with existential types, call `draw` on each, and get the right implementation for each.

Comment: @AlexeyPetrushin As for the embedding: Yes, that's why it's a flawed approach regardless of paradigm. I mentioned it for completeness and because it mirrors the example in the question (which suffers from the very same problems).